# Create a list concatenating a list element and character string in R

Tags: r, list, nested-loops, concatenation

I am trying to create a list of requests called `requests`. I have a list of hundreds of products, but I simplify for this example code.

```
products <- list()
products[[1]] <- c("77295T", "67619Q", "9528QR")
products[[2]] <- c("B7295T", "676193")
requests <- vector("list",length(products[[1]]))
length(requests)
i <- 1
for (i in 1:(length(products[[1]])))  {
    requests[[i]] <- cat('"',noquote(products[[1]][[i]]),'~XPORT"', sep = '')  
   }
```

results in:

```
"77295T~XPORT""67619Q~XPORT""9528QR~XPORT"
```

The end result I am looking for is a request list of length 3 with the following three elements:

```
requests[[1]] 
"77295T~XPORT"

requests[[2]]
"67619Q~XPORT"

requests[[3]]
"9528QR~XPORT"
```

Background: Eventually I want `requests` to be a nested list (a list of lists); in my dataset `products` is a list, so that is why I provide `products[[2]]`, even though my question relates to just iterating over `products[[1]]. Replacing`products[[1]]` with an equivalent products1 also creates the same output.  That code is here:

```
products1 <- c("77295T", "67619Q", "9528QR")
i <- 1
for (i in 1:(length(products1))) {
  requests[[i]] <- cat('"',noquote(products1[[i]]),'~XPORT"', sep = '')  
  }
```

This more simple code provides the same results:

```
"77295T~XPORT""67619Q~XPORT""9528QR~XPORT"
```

I do realize that the for loop I called may not be necessary. I am trying to gradually learn how to "vectorize" my R code. Any suggestion for further vector-elegance in this code would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably `requests <- as.list(paste(products[[1]], "XPORT", sep="~"))` is the simplest answer.

Comment: `lapply(products[[1]], function(x){ paste0(x, "~XPORT")})` should also work

Comment: @lmo you mean, this code without the loop, right? That does the trick.

Comment: Yes. A loop is not needed with that code. In this instance, `paste` does the work under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is this:

```
requests <- lapply(products[[1]], function(x){paste0(x, "~XPORT")})
requests
# [[1]]
# [1] "77295T~XPORT"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "67619Q~XPORT"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "9528QR~XPORT"
```

And if you wish to do this to all vectors in `products`, I would use a loop:

```
request <- list()
for(i in 1:length(products)){
   request[[i]] <- lapply(products[[i]], function(x){paste0(x, "~XPORT")})
}
```

I'm sure this is just one of many ways to accomplish this.

## Edit

An alternative to the above without any loops, would be to use `sapply` instead of `for`

```
sapply(products, function(y){
  lapply(y, function(x) paste0(x, "~XPORT"))
})
```

Comment: Both parts of this code works. Thank you. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the second loop. I tried `req4 <- lapply(prods, function(x){paste0(x, "~XPORT")})`, but that doesn't generate a nested list, just a list of two, where the first looks like this: `"77295T~XPORT" "67619Q~XPORT" "9528QR~XPORT"`

Comment: @mrlcpa I just added an alternative that works without using a loop

Comment: The alternative without loops works, thank you. When I replace sapply with lapply, the resulting `all.equal(request1,request2)` brings back `TRUE`. So I guess in this case they function the same.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ken ,to get the nested list without using the loop, **as.list()** might be helpful on this case.

```
products <- list()
products[[1]] <- c("77295T", "67619Q", "9528QR")
products[[2]] <- c("B7295T", "676193")
requests <- lapply(products, function(x){ as.list(paste0(x, "~XPORT"))})
requests

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "77295T~XPORT"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "67619Q~XPORT"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "9528QR~XPORT"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "B7295T~XPORT"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "676193~XPORT"
```